# Detect a click on image inside nav element

Tags: html, css

Simplfied version of the code:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div>
        <img class="normal-logo" onclick="runFunction()" src="abc.png">
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.normal-logo {
    height:3em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0.625em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #2F373F;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.25em;
    line-height: 4.25em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Since the image is inside the nav, the clicks on the image aren't getting detected.

Comment: Hidden as in not visible?

Comment: What is the css for this element?

Comment: Img is hidden mean? display none, opacity 0 or?

Comment: Sorry, wrong choice of words. I mean the element is inside the nav, therefore the clicks don't reach it. It is not hidden.

Comment: @the_it_crowd Post the css for the image element or the parent div, which ever one has styles. And post where you defined the function, are there any errors in console? Your code should work if properly coded https://jsfiddle.net/v0gz4gu1/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited. Added css.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you image is not hidden by css rule like `display: hidden;`

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <div>
        <img id="my-image" src="abc.png">
    </div>
</nav>
<script>
  const image = document.getElementById('my-image');
  image.addEventListener('click', runFunction);
  
  function runFunction() {
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not working :( runFunction still doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your code should work. See below.

Why might it not work?

Possibilities:

- You did not define runFunction() properly.
- Your image is not loading properly
- You have a typo somewhere
- You have another error crashing Javascript on this page, perhaps a cross-origin issue or some other faulty function.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function runFunction() {
  clicks++;
  var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
  counter.innerText = 'runFunction ' + clicks;

}
```

```css
.normal-logo {
    height:3em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0.625em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #2F373F;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.25em;
    line-height: 4.25em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: default;
}

#counter {
  margin-top: 100px
  }
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <div>
        <img class="normal-logo" onclick="runFunction()" src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract">
    </div>
</nav>
<div id='counter'></div>
```